# Netlogo-initial position + measure minimum distance between a patch and a turtle/patch

Tags: position, distance, netlogo, min

I wrote this code, however, I don't know if it is correct (it is technical-grammatically correct). If you have any break time from eating Christmas cookies, please have a look and comment if my code is correct and Netlogo will do what I need.

My intention: on a map, create 6 subway stations, measure the distance from any patch on this map to the nearest subway (dt-subway), measure the distance from any patch on this map to the nearest patch with color green (dt-park)

```
breed [subways subway] 
patches-own [dt-park dt-subway]
to set-patches 
   create-subways 1 [set shape "ubahn" set size 2.5 setxy -14 -17]  
   create-subways 1 [set shape "ubahn" set size 2.5 setxy -50 -13]   
   create-subways 1 [set shape "ubahn" set size 2.5 setxy -27 -26]   
   create-subways 1 [set shape "ubahn" set size 2.5 setxy 20 11]     
   create-subways 1 [set shape "ubahn" set size 2.5 setxy 48 -20]    
   create-subways 1 [set shape "ubahn" set size 2.5 setxy 55 -35]  
   ask patches [set dt-park min-one-of patches with [pcolor = 64] [distance myself]] 
   ask patches [set dt-subway min-one-of subways [distance myself]]
```

Will this do what I want? Especially with the dt-subway?

Comment: it looks fine to me does it run?

Comment: You can use `inspect` (right click on what you want to inspect) to see the values of variables for turtles or patches. Inspect some turtles and patches and look to see if the values are what you expect.

Comment: If you are going to use `distance`, make sure you have wrapping set to reflect how you want.distances measured.

Comment: @King-Ink yes, it runs. thank you.

Comment: @JenB thank you. i inspected and they reported what I think it should be. dt-park (patches x y), dt-subway (subway 1). So what I have now is a number or a specific patch? Now I have to kind of tell the turtle to move to patches with smallest value of dt-park and dt-subway. Or if the patch they are staying have the dt-park and dt-subway further than the average distance of this area, they should move. How should I do it? in which ever way i think it doesn't make sense.

Comment: @Alan thank you for your suggestion. i googled wrapping set but don't understand it.

Comment: So the code above works - it is returning the name of the closest subway (which is a turtle) and the coordinates of the closest park. Look at the command `move-to`. If you have a new problem, please open a new question.

Comment: @HoaLai  See https://ccl.northwestern.edu/netlogo/docs/programming.html#topology

Comment: @Alan oh I see. Thank you. I will change the wrap setting!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe you can take a look at the Voronoi Model in the library,... essentially you are trying to do the same...